# You do not have the necessary permissions to use msAccess 2000 db

Tags: database, ms-access

I'm trying to open an old MS Access 2000 Database that was working on windows XP, so that i can migrate the old DB in a new application. The DB was created by the previous old WPF application and I need to find a way to open it. I installed MS Access 2000 and used a program that generated the right password for the db but there is still this message that pops up:

> You do not have the necessary permissions to use C:/pathToDB.MDB object. Have your system administrator or the person who created this object establish the appropriate permissions for you.

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Earlier versions before 2007 had something called as the MDW (Microsoft Access Workgroup) file with the MDB .

If you cannot find this, you can create one. To create this file, first create a new shortcut Right click New > Shortcut>. When asked type the location of the item. You will need to enter the following, replacing MDB/MDW> to where your files are located and the version of Office you are using. It may be worth opening notepad so you can get the path right and then copy and paste.

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\MSACCESS.EXE" ".mdb" /wrkgrp ".mdw" /user
```

Replace Office14 with your version of Microsoft office that is installed. To find this, browse to “C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\ and note the “Office” folder.

Use this new shortcut to open your file. It should hopefully sort it out.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. It just asked me for username and password before asking me for the password of the db and then showed me the same message. I'm afraid it has something to do with diferent kind of permissions

Comment: Can you find the MDW file?

Comment: No there is no MDW created by the program. Although i created one by creating a new database and then adding this security file. Then I used this MDW together with the first database that i want to open and it seems that it works because i pass the first level credentials of the MDW and then it asks me for the database password (a second pop up)

Comment: Is the second pop up your problem? In that case it is not easy to decrypt the DB. I am not sure if there is any other third party software that would allow you to do this either.

Comment: yes the problem is in the second pop up. And the thing is that the password generated from a program that I used is the right one. Meaning if i put another password in the second pop up a different kind of message pops up. But nonetheless with the right password the message with the necessary permission appears.

Comment: I have to mention there is an ldb file created by the program. I don't know if that helps. Should i give up trying?

Comment: I have the same issue! I have just secured the DB and created 2 users. Everything works when I log in with the user who belongs to Admins group. But when I try to log in with user who belongs to Users group I get this error...

Answer (score 1):

delete the .ldb file and this should solve your problem. The .ldb file is created when a new session is created. If the program crashes, the .ldb file will not be deleted.

Hope this helps you.